# Access element replaced with ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template, ng-content

I've tried to create some tabs component that some how can be used like Angular Material Component.

But the solution I've made is not right and is buggy

I've used
`document.getElementsByTagName('app-tab')`

This is tabs component template

[image]

This is the way it used

[image]

I wanted to access `app-tab` label attribute value, but don't know how to access it from app-tabs, that used `ng-content`
Thank you so much in advance

#### The Answer

This is called content projection

Detailed introduction can be found here

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it by using @ContentChild or @ContentChildren decorators. you can read about them here :-

https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren

https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild

Comment: Thank you for early answer, but those technique require directives and ContentChildren and ContentChild is not working just like that

Comment: directives are not required, you can use component name. or give that component a tag with hash like #project and use 'project' in round brackets of decorator.

Comment: You were right, I didn't know that, than you so much